# write SQL join query using Querysets in Django

Tags: sql, django

am trying to write join query on two tables using django Queryset,so need suggestions to write
 SQL join query using Querysets in Django..

here is My Query and Models of Tables

```
   SELECT t.time, d.id2
   FROM  disp_b_time t JOIN disp_dispatch d ON t.id1 = d.id2
   WHERE  t.status = "completed" AND d.status = 0  AND d.vehicle_id =1 

class B_Time(models.Model):
    id1 =  models.ForeignKey(Book)
    dispatcher= models.ForeignKey(D)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=B_STATUS)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
    register = models.DateField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)


class Dispatch(models.Model):
    id2 = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle)
    driveId = models.ForeignKey(Drive)
    dispId  = models.ForeignKey(D)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=STATUS)
    register = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Please be more specific here. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Include your models and a description of your desired query.

Comment: @jonafato Good, but he should at least show something he tried before asking the question.

Comment: Your model is not match for your join query. Atleast you should have book_id or dispID to join both table

Answer (score 0):

```
d = Dipatch.objects.filter(vehicle__pk=1)\
                   .filter(status=0).filter(dispID__b_time__status='completed')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why

```
d = Dipatch.objects.filter(vehicle__pk=1)\
                   .filter(status=0).filter(dispID__b_time__status='completed')
```

?

We can simply write it as

```
d = Dipatch.objects.filter(vehicle__pk=1, status=0, dispID__b_time__status='completed')
```

Comment: but both versions are not correct. the join is made on `id1 = id2`